# Pandas: Efficiently compare two columns and assign match to new column

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe, for-loop

The data as pandas dataframe df1:

```
id | name   | year | month | day | hour | minute    + identifier
--------------------------------------------------
  1 | Steve  | 2018 |    12 |  01 |   00 |   00
  2 | Jeff   | 2018 |    12 |  01 |   00 |   00
  3 | Elon   | 2018 |    12 |  01 |   00 |   00
  4 | Satya  | 2018 |    12 |  01 |   00 |   00
  5 | Tim    | 2018 |    12 |  01 |   00 |   00
  6 | Mark   | 2018 |    12 |  01 |   00 |   00
  7 | Steve  | 2018 |    12 |  01 |   00 |   15
  8 | Jeff   | 2018 |    12 |  01 |   00 |   15
  9 | Elon   | 2018 |    12 |  01 |   00 |   15
 10 | Satya  | 2018 |    12 |  01 |   00 |   15
 11 | Tim    | 2018 |    12 |  01 |   00 |   15
 12 | Mark   | 2018 |    12 |  01 |   00 |   15
 13 | Steve  | 2018 |    12 |  01 |   00 |   30
```

Another dataframe df2:

```
 id | name   | identifier  
--------------------------
  1 | Steve  |    ap1
  2 | Jeff   |    am1  
  3 | Elon   |    te1   
  4 | Satya  |    ms1  
  5 | Tim    |    ap2  
  6 | Mark   |    fb1
```

A column has to be added to df1 by comparing it to a column of df2 with the names as identifiers. If the name match, the corresponding value has to be added.

My current solution:

```
for i in range(len(df1)):
    _ = df1['name'].str.contains(name['name'].tolist()[i])
    df_target['identifier'][_] = sws_stations['identifier'].tolist()[i]
```

At first I create a boolean series _ and assign row wise. This operation takes very long, because it's a dataset of million entries. I thought of using something more efficient, but I'm stuck.
(I can only guess to use list comprehensions or dicts)

Comment: Check `df1.merge(df2[['name', 'identifier']], on='name', how='left')`